# Creating VIsual Studio Addins with Iron Ruby

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ironruby

Some time ago at one of the .Net conferences John Lam gave a demonstration of how to use Iron Ruby to create VS add in's. At the time it seemed alot easier than what you currently have to do to create new VS add in's. Where can I get an example of this or does someone know a better starting point for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post on the IronRuby forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/177776#778873) out.

You would have to create visual studio add-in with C# that hosts the DLR and IronRuby.
But you wouldn't be saved from having to deal with EnvDTE which is the horrible part of VS 2k8 extensibility.

To do this in VS 2010 should be much easier.

Comment: Seems like anyone doing new Visual Studio add-in work would be wise to wait / target VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

John Lam showed that demo when he had IronRuby support in VS. This support hasn't made it past the POC stage. 
The demo also used a rubyaddin.rb file which isn't available currently.

These two things probably made this demo as fluent as it was...

However, once you have some template of IronRuby VS addin project, I guess that writing VS addins with IronRuby will be much easier from that  point on. I'll try to come up with such a project soon.

Comment: Please let me know when you do , its much appreciated